# Why this simple Junit 5 test is not working

Tags: java, exception, junit5

I am using JUnit 5. When I debug, I can see my code is throwing FileStorageException exception from the implementation. But it gives this error message:-

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnnecessaryStubbingException: 
Unnecessary stubbings detected.
Clean & maintainable test code requires zero unnecessary code.
Following stubbings are unnecessary (click to navigate to relevant line of code):
  1. -> at com.spark.profile.service.ProfileServiceImplTest.testThrowFileStorageExceptionWhenNull(ProfileServiceImplTest.java:67)
Please remove unnecessary stubbings or use 'lenient' strictness. More info: javadoc for UnnecessaryStubbingException class.

What is wrong? How to test this exception by Junit 5?

```
    @Test
void testThrowFileStorageExceptionWhenNull() {
    // act
    when(profileService.storeFile(null, null)).thenReturn(null);
    //assert
    assertThrows(FileStorageException.class,
            () -> {
                profileServiceImpl.storeFile(null, null);
            }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UnnecessaryStubbingException means you've mocked the return of something that isn't even being called. In your case that is `when(profileService.storeFile(null, null)).thenReturn(null);`. Deleting that line should solve your problem.